# In Excel - how to countif() for " (double quotes)

Tags: excel, countif

I can use `=countif()` to find cells with special characters. For example, If I'm looking for cells with '!' I can use `=countif("*!*")`.

How do I do this if I'm looking for cells with '"' (double quotes).

I tried the following but they don't work:

```
=countif("*"*")
=countif("*~"*")
=countif(~"*"*")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*" & CHAR(34) & "*")
```

[image]

and if you wanted to count cells with a **pair of double-quotes**:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*" & CHAR(34)  & CHAR(34)& "*")
```

You can modify this to count "problem" cells, like cells containing `CHAR(160)`,etc.

Comment: Aw, I think I misread `Double Quotes` to mean `""` not `"`.  I believe you are correct.

Comment: Great - I did not know about CHAR(34).

Comment: @val  thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

You can use double double quotes like this: `"abc""def"` to create the string `abc"def`

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*""*")
```

Comment: It is sad to see this correct answer downvoted. [`Char(34)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36896168/11683) is not *the* way, it's *a* way, and arguably, it does you more harm than good if you don't know how to escape quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you are looking for`"`:

```
=COUNTIF(Range,"*"&CHAR(34)&"*")
```

If you are looking for `""`:

```
=COUNTIF(Range,"*"&CHAR(34)&CHAR(34)&"*")
```